# Remove after first "/" from the left in Excel

Tags: excel

Sorry I'm a new to excel formula and need help with this.

```
D:/folder A/ folder B.1/text_01.txt
D:/folder A/Folder C/ folder C.1/text_02.msg
```

I like to remove all the text from the right after the first occurrence "/" counting from the right.

So I would get the followings.

```
D:/folder A/ folder B.1
D:/folder A/Folder C/ folder C.1
```

I'd appreciacite if you guys can help out this.

Comment: Confused, your title says left and your question right...

Answer (score 1):

Using an Excel formula, we can try:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))),1) - 1)
```

assuming that your file path is in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more formula approach which works with your data.

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/"&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99)),"")`

Comment: It **does** work with his data, but if the substring at the end happens to be duplicated within the string, it will remove both.  eg. `D:/folder/A/folder B.1/text_01.txt/A --> D:/folder/folder B.1/text_01.txt`.  Note that both `A`'s are removed.  Unlikely to happen in full file paths, with a file type at the end, but a cause for concern when applying this in a more general fashion.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Agree. I took that approach based user's sample which shows file extensions which are an unlikely candidate to come in folder names!

Comment: Since other people search SO for answers with data that might not exactly match the OP's data, but might be similar (eg `How do I remove the last word from a string`), I prefer to highlight or explain certain short-comings in my answers, when they might be relevant.  But this is a personal choice.  Sometimes, even the data in a question is a made up sample, and the real data is different enough that a supplied solution won't work (not the case here, though).